# how to add tooltip to pushpin on windowsphone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've been doing a essay about map on windows phone. I added pushpins default into map and its content is a image. I want to show information when I tap or click on pushpin, but I don't know what to do. I've just thought about use tooltip to show info, but I can't do it. 
here is my createpushpin function.
can you help me?  thank you for all kind of you!

```
    private void CreateNewPushpin(object selectedItem)
    {

        var pushpinPrototype = selectedItem as Pushpinsmodel;
        var pushpinicon = pushpinPrototype.Icon;

        Pushpin pushpins = new Pushpin() { Tag = adress.Name };
        pushpins.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        pushpins.Location = new GeoCoordinate(lad, long);
        ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush() { 
         ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
        (pushpinicon)};

        Ellipse elip = new Ellipse()
        {
            Fill = image,

            Name = adress.Name,
            StrokeThickness = 10,
            Height = 30,
            Width = 30
        };
            pushpins.Content = elip;
            var tooltipText = new ToolTip { Content = adress.Name};
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(pushpins, tooltipText);
        map1.Children.Add(pushpins); 
        listpushpin.Add(pushpins);
              this.map1.SetView(pushpins.Location, 18.0);
```

}

Comment: are you referring to tooltips, which is shown in floating bubble in desktop applications. Cause that might not be possible/feasible in a touch environment. Tough you could use a substitute like textblock elsewhere.

Comment: Thank Master chief! Can you guide more detail? I'm a newbie in WP programming. the best you show me with code. Thank you again.